# How to pull a variable from one function to another

Tags: python

```
    def letterChoice():
        playerLetter = input('Please choose X or O.').upper()
        if playerLetter in ['X','O']:
          print('The game will now begin.')
        while playerLetter not in ['X','O']:
          playerLetter = input('Choose X or O.').upper()
        if playerLetter == 'X':
          computerLetter = 'O'
        else:
          computerLetter = 'X'
        turnChooser()
    def turnChooser():
        choice = input("Would you like to go first, second or decide by coin toss?(enter 1, 2 or c) ")
        while choice not in ["1","2","c"]:
          choice = input("Please enter 1, 2 or c. ")
        if choice == 1:
          print("G")
          cur_turn = letterChoice.playerLetter()
        elif choice == 2:
          print("H")
        else:
          print("P")
        moveTaker()
```

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to inherit playerLetter into turnChooser(), I've tried putting playerLetter into the brackets of each function but they don't pass and create an argument error and the `print("G")` and so on are simply there to see if the code works but whenever I enter 1 or 2 "P" is outputted.

Comment: how are you running this code exactly?

Comment: @melgart what do you mean?

Comment: in the code you've included above, you just show the definitions of two functions -- one of which calls the other. how do you run this code? did you put this code into a python file and run it with the python interpreter from the command line? how did you execute it?

Comment: They're apart of a larger piece of code in an python file and ran it from there @melgart

Comment: What do you mean by "inherit"?  These are functions, not classes.   Passing  values into a function is done by passing parameters, and out of functions by `return`.  You are doing neither.

Comment: Note that you define functions here, but when you write `letterChoice.playerLetter()` you do as if `letterChoice` was a class. If you want it to be a class you need to [define it as such](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is use `playerLetter` from `letterChoice` in `turnChooser` to determine which letter will go first in the game of Tic Tac Toe. I don't know the best way to do so I presumed using functions would be the way forward @cdarke @jojo

Comment: Replace the final statement of `letterChoice` with:  `turnChooser(playerLetter)`.  The first line of `turnChooser`:  `def turnChooser(playerLetter):`.  Then `playerLetter` will be available in the second function.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'playerLetter'` when I enter playerLetter into those parameters I get that error.

Comment: You need to use Function `Attributes`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using classes: [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

This should be the code:

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cur_turn = ''
        self.choise = ''
        self.playerLetter = ''
        self.computerLetter = ''

    def letterChoice(self):
        while True:
            self.playerLetter = input('Please choose X or O.').upper()
            if self.playerLetter in ['X','O']:
                print('The game will now begin.')
                if playerLetter == 'X':
                   self.computerLetter = 'O'
                else:
                   self.computerLetter = 'X'
                break
            else:
                print ('Please enter only X or O')      

     def turnChooser(self):
         while True:
             self.choice = input("Would you like to go first, second or decide by coin toss? (enter 1, 2 or c) ")
             if self.choice in ["1","2","c"]:
                 if self.choice == 1:
                   print("G")
                   self.cur_turn = self.playerLetter()
                 elif self.choice == 2:
                   print("H")
                 else:
                   print("P")
                 break
             else:
                 print ('Please enter 1, 2 or c')

game = Game()
game.letterChoice()
game.turnChooser()

# If you want to read any of the variables in Game just write 'self.VARIABLE_NAME'
```

Comment: You define `playerLetter` as an attribute (a string) of `Game` object. You cannot write `self.playerLetter()` then. `playerLetter` is not a method!

Comment: Can you put an working example ? show the OP your method works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define function Attributes for `playerLatter`

For EX:

```
def foo():
    foo.playerletter=input('Please choose X or O.').upper()


>>> foo()
Please choose X or O.x

>>> foo.playerLetter
'X'
```

Accessing from another function

```
def bar():
    variable=foo.playerLetter
    print(variable)


>>> bar()
X
>>>
```

You can always check what Attributes are available for a given function

```
>>> [i for i in dir(foo) if not i.startswith('_')]
['playerLetter']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit turnchooser() to turnchooser(var), then when calling the function pass the letter to the function like this:

def LetterChoice():

```
   Code...

   turnchooser(playerletter)
```

And,

```
def turnchooser(var):
       Code...
```

The letter will be placed in a variable called var, which means your code will use the letter as var not playerletter.

Of Course you can change the names to whatever you like.

You could add as many variables to the function however they all should have something assigned to them, aka you can't call the previous function like so:

```
turnchooser()
```

Unless you assign it a default value:

```
def turnchooser(var = 'x')
```

This way whenever the function is called the value of "var" is x unless stated otherwise.

Note that if you want to pass it from one function to another, u either have to assign the letter to a variable then call the function outside the "LetterChoice" or call it in the definition of "LetterChoice"

Answer (score 0):

Within the function that has the variable in it type:

```
global variableName
```

Obviously change variableName to whatever the variable is actually called. Hope this helps!

Tommy